# Coffeescript commented license

Tags: coffeescript

Here are two types of comment:

```
# Hello I can be viewed by the client. I'm a license or whatever
# I'm a personal note. I don't want to appear in the compiled js
```

It appears that in the compiled js, neither comment appears. I want to show a license, so how should I do this. What other types of comments are there with coffeescript. A shown multiline comment would be perfect for a license, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#strings):

> Sometimes you'd like to pass a block comment through to the generated JavaScript. For example, when you need to embed a licensing header at the top of a file. Block comments, which mirror the syntax for block strings, are preserved in the generated code.

That even comes the example that:

```
###
SkinnyMochaHalfCaffScript Compiler v1.0
Released under the MIT License
###
```

becomes

```
/*
SkinnyMochaHalfCaffScript Compiler v1.0
Released under the MIT License
 */
```

in the generated JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, multi lined comments are automatically compiled in the js, single line comments are not?

Comment: No, why would they? Comments are for people, the generated JavaScript is for the JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: @muistooshort it is really a design choice. just as block comments are carried over into the target JS code, so could be inline comments.